# The correct usage of the phrasal verb "mean for"

Tags: phrasal-verbs

> Many of the notes are ***meant for*** readers with some formal
>   training in mathematics or physics.

I was wondering is this the correct usage of the phrasal verb "mean for", as my dictionary shows that it must be followed by a "to do" part:

> **mean for *somebody* to do *something***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That usage is perfectly correct. It means that many of the notes are thought to be used from readers with some formal training in mathematics or physics.

The [OALD reports that usage](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/mean#mean_1__78) under "have a purpose," "mean something for somebody/something."

> The chair was clearly meant for a child.

The example sentence means the chair was thought to be used from a child, not an adult.